# Web app doesn't reflect the status of requests to the web service back to the user

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api2

**EDIT 2**
I've stepped through the code execution from form submission to the web service's completion of its execution and it seems that it's timing out sending an email to the user which probably means something iffy with my SMTP Client details. I'll try with google and see how that works out.
**END EDIT 2**

I'm writing a web app that sends data to a web service I wrote which stores the data in the database.

Unfortunately, whether the POSTs are successful or not, the web app does nothing after submitting the data. There's no indication at all that anything's happened as a result of the submission.

I'm doing the POST via ajax on my View:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
        if (!data.IsOK) {
            DisplayError(data.Title, data.Message, data.Error);
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/User")';
        }
        return;
    });

    return false;
});
```

My Controller handles the POST to the server as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(User source)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["AdminCookie"] == null)
        return RedirectToRoute("Home");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49474/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/user", source);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return Json(new
                        {
                            Message = "Success",
                            IsOK = bool.TrueString
                        });
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ReportError(ex, "CREATE");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

**EDIT 1**
Looking over this code, it occurred to me that I'm not doing anything if the response status code is not a success code, however, I also know from experience that I'm not likely to get much useful information from the response if this is the case. At least not based on my current code... How can I improve on that?
**END EDIT**

As we can see, as soon as the success Json is returned to the View, it should be redirected to the "Index" view on the same route or else, if there was an error, it should display an error modal of my own design to inform the user what's wrong.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]User Source)
{
    try
    {
        User u = new User();
        u.EmailAddress = Source.EmailAddress;
        u.FirstName = Source.FirstName;
        u.LastName = Source.LastName;
        u.Password = Hashing.CreatePassword(Source.Password);
        u.RoleId = Source.RoleId;
        u.Role = db.Roles.Single(x => x.Id == u.RoleId);

        db.Users.Add(u);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ReportError(ex, "POST USER");
    }
}

private HttpResponseMessage ReportError(Exception ex, string Action = "")
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Error actioning request: [ {0} ]", ex.Message));

    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error");
    response.Content = new StringContent(ex.ToString(), Encoding.Unicode);

    return response;
}
```

This is my first time working on and with a web service so I'm pretty much operating on what I've learned from some tutorials and [what seems like] common sense.

Am I misunderstanding something here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint here: HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/user", source); and make sure you are getting a response. If you are not then you are just returning an empty view and the "data" does not exist for your ajax to evaluate IsOk.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(User source)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["AdminCookie"] == null)
        return RedirectToRoute("Home");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49474/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/user", source); //debug here to ensure you are getting a response

                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var dataObject = serializer.Deserialize<SomeResponse>(response);

                if (dataObject.Success)
                {
                    return Responder("Success", true);
                }
            }
            return Responder();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ReportError(ex, "CREATE");
            return Responder();
        }
    }
}

private object Responder(string message = "Did not succeed", bool succeeded = false)
{
    return new
         {
             Message = message,
             IsOK = succeeded
         };
}

public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]User Source)
{
    try
    {
        User u = new User();
        u.EmailAddress = Source.EmailAddress;
        u.FirstName = Source.FirstName;
        u.LastName = Source.LastName;
        u.Password = Hashing.CreatePassword(Source.Password);
        u.RoleId = Source.RoleId;
        u.Role = db.Roles.Single(x => x.Id == u.RoleId);

        db.Users.Add(u);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return new SomeResponse().Success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ReportError(ex, "POST USER");
    }
}

public class SomeResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me since my service only does a `return CreateResponse("HttpStatusCode.OK);` that this might actually be the problem but I'm not sure how to put something useful in there... The last time I tried adding StringContent to the response, the browser tried to download the Create page

Comment: In your post method change this: HttpResponseMessage to this: IHttpActionResult and return an object: { Success="true" }

Comment: I did this but its complaining about Success not being defined -> `IHttpActionResult response = new object() { Success = "true" };`

Comment: Mkay well, I AM getting a response... HttpStatusCode 500... I'll update the question

Comment: You'll get a 500 now if you changed the return type to IHttpActionResult because in your catch block you are still returning ReportError(ex, "CREATE"); You'll need to change that but for now comment it out so you can get the main part working.

Comment: It also just occurred to me that you may not be using a WebAPI project and calling this from an MVC project. If that's the case instead of returning an ActionResult (which is looking for a view) return a JsonResult.